# Django custom template filter to highlight a column in a block of text

Tags: regex, django-templates

I'm rendering a list in an HTML template using {{ my_list | join:"<\br>"}} , and it appears as...

```
$GPGGA,062511,2816.8178,S,15322.3185,E,6,04,2.6,72.6,M,37.5,M,,*68
$GPGGA,062512,2816.8177,S,15322.3184,E,1,04,2.6,72.6,M,37.5,M,,*62
$GPGGA,062513,2816.8176,S,15322.3181,E,1,04,2.6,72.6,M,37.5,M,,*67
$GPGGA,062514,2816.8176,S,15322.3180,E,1,03,2.6,72.6,M,37.5,M,,*66
$GPGGA,062515,2816.8176,S,15322.3180,E,6,03,2.6,72.6,M,37.5,M,,*60
```

I am attempting to use regular expressions to insert the CSS at the 4th and 5th commas so I can highlight the text in this column, however I'm not able to figure out the expression to do this. Other methods to achieve this also appreciated.

Other info:

1) each line ends with a '\n'. Although this can be removed and the HTML display is unchanged, I've left it in for the regular expression to use if required.
2) The string will not always have a nice header such as '$GPGGA' in this example, although I could add one to help ID the start of the line if required by the regex.
3) The columns may not be a uniform number of characters as indicated in this example.

The filters I'm working on are as follows

```
@register.filter(is_safe=True)
def highight_start(text):
    return re.sub('regex to find 4th comma in each line', ",<span class='my_highlight'>", text, flags=re.MULTILINE)

@register.filter(is_safe=True)
def highight_end(text):
    return re.sub('regex to find 5th comma in each line', "</span>,", text, flags=re.MULTILINE)
```

Regards

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can achieve that by *replacing* the 5th value with the value itself wrapped in your `<span>` tags.

RegEx: `^((?:[\w\d\.\$]+,){4})([\d\.]+)`
Replacement: `\1<span class='my_highlight'>\2</span>`

Explained demo here: http://regex101.com/r/cX5iA0

Note: I assumed the 5th value will be digits and dots

Comment: Thanks, this got me going.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks @ka, who got me ontrack with this solution. My working filter uses:

```
expression = '^((?:[^,]+,){4})([^,]+)'
replace = r'\g<1><span class="my_highlight">\g<2></span>'

#[^,] also allows matching of hidden HTML tags in the text
#To get the groups to insert back into the text and not be overwritten, they need to be referenced as indicated in 'replace'.
```